# Autowire not finding the Bean in Maven multi module project

Tags: java, spring, maven, autowired, multi-module

I have split my maven project into multiple modules. In one of the modules, service-module, I have a class SomeBusinessDelegate with a @Service annotation, and in another module, service-api (which service-module has a dependency on), I have an interface ISomeBusinessDelegate which is implemented by SomeBusinessDelegate. The whole multi module project builds and compiles when I do a clean/install with maven. I have set up my applicationContext.xml (which is in service-module) to scan for the correct beans but when I try and deploy on tomcat 7 I get an exception telling me that ISomeBusinessDelegate doesnt have any available beans implementing it "Unsatisfied dependency of type [interface com.x.y.z.ISomeBusinessDelegate]: expected at least 1 matching bean". Is there something obvious that I'm doing wrong? Do I need another applicationContext.xml in the service-api module?

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">

<context:component-scan
    base-package="com.x.y.z.request, com.x.y.z.service, com.x.y.z.dao" />
<context:annotation-config />
<tx:annotation-driven />
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db" />
    <property name="username" value="user" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />
</bean>
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" p:jpaVendorAdapter-ref="jpaAdapter">
    <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
    p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory" />
<bean id="jpaAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
    <property name="showSql" value="true" />
</bean>
```

RequestService.java

```
package com.x.y.z.request;

@Component
@Path("/request")
public class RequestService
{
    @Autowired
    private ISomeBusinessDelegate delegate;

}
```

SomeBusinessDelegate.java (ISomeBusinessDelegate.java exists in com.x.y.z.service in the service-api module)

```
package com.x.y.z.service;

@Service
public class SomeBusinessDelegate extends GenericBusinessDelegate implements ISomeBusinessDelegate
{
    @Autowired
    private ISomeDao dao;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<ISomething> getSomeThings()
    {
         return dao.someDaoCall();
    }
}
```

SomeDao.java (GenericDao contains the EntityManager annotated with @PersistenceContext)

```
package com.x.y.z.dao;

@Repository
public class SomeDao extends GenericDao implements ISomeDao
{
    @Override
    public List<ISomething> someDaoCall()
    {
        //does some sql call
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us your your `applicationContext.xml` as well as the class where a `ISomeBusinessDelegate` should be autowired.

Comment: Is your `SomeBusinessDelegate` class in a package declared in the `component-scan`?

Comment: yes, it's in com.x.y.z.service

Comment: Please show the skeleton of that class. Everything seems fine.

Comment: which class? RequestService, SomeBusinessDelegate or ISomeBusinessDelegate?

Comment: `SomeBusinessDelegate`

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. Try removing the `@Service` annotation and explicitly declaring a `<bean>` for `SomeBusinessDelegate`.

Comment: so there doesnt need to be an applicationContext in the service-api module as well? The troubling thing is if I do a eclipse heirarchy on ISomeBusinessDelegate (in service-api) it shows nothing, because the interface that SomeBusinessDelegate implements is the ISomeBusinessDelegate class file in the maven dependencies from the maven install of the service-api module...

Comment: You need to understand that a context file on its own doesn't do anything. Yours works because you use some kind of `ApplicationContext` class to load it.

Comment: Not sure, but do you not need getters & setters still when you Autowire?